# Comparing objects which contain two other object references

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a Java class that contains two object references from another class. 
i.e I have two classes. An instance of Class A contains two instances from Class B. 
Basically i'm trying to compare a pair of objects, with another pair of objects, with a method that returns true only if the two pair of objects are identical. I seem to only be able to compare the locations in memory, rather than the Objects themselves.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Apologies for the vagueness! here is my class for creating basic objects.

```
public class B {

String name;
int number;

B(String name, int number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}
```

And here is my class which creates and object, containing two object references of Class B.

```
public class A{

Object one;
Object two;

A(Object one, Object two) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
}
```

Objects of class b are invoked by:

```
B bob = new B("Bob", 22);
B bobby = new B("Bobby", 22);
B robert = new B("Robert", 32);
```

Objects of class A are invoked by:

```
A firstPair = new A(bob,bobby);
A secondPair = new A(bobby,robert);
```

So my problem is overridng the equals() method to compare two instances of class A. Hopefully this is more clear, sorry again!

Comment: override `equals` and `hashcode` method. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/

Comment: It could share the code of your `A` and `B` classes, it might help us to help you better.

Comment: I added some code hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume what you mean is

```
class A{
    private B b1;
    private B b2;
}

A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
```

You want to see if a1 is the same as a2

To do that add override equals in class A and class B

```
class B{
    public boolean equals(B that){
         //compare their attributes (what makes 2 B equals)
         return this.name.equals(that.b) && this.number == that.number;
    }
}

class A{
    private B b1;
    private B b2;
   public boolean equals(A anotherA){
      return b1.equals(anotherA.b1) && b2.equals(anotherA.b2); // (A is equal if both b1 and b2 are equal)
   }
}
```

Comment: This basically correct, however, does noz handle cases where b1 or b2 are null. Also, when overriding equals() one should always override hashCode() too. Finally, some IDEs provide code generation that does all that for you (e.g. IntelliJ, AndroidStudio)